# Kак сделать чтобы при добавлении бота в группу он отправлял сообщение?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Как сделать чтобы при добавлении бота в группу он отправлял сообщение?

Пробовал через `message_handler`. Вывод telegram:

```
{
  "update_id": 1111,
  "message": {
    "message_id": 1111,
    "from": {
      "id": 11111111,
      "is_bot": false,
      "first_name": "hello",
      "username": "hello",
      "language_code": "ru"
    },
    "chat": {
      "id": 111111,
      "title": "hello",
      "type": "group",
      "all_members_are_administrators": true
    },
    "date": 1583922351,
    "new_chat_participant": {
      "id": 11111111,
      "is_bot": true,
      "first_name": "hello",
      "username": "hello"
    },
    "new_chat_member": {
      "id": 111111,
      "is_bot": true,
      "first_name": "hello",
      "username": "hello"
    },
    "new_chat_members": [
      {
        "id": 11111111,
        "is_bot": true,
        "first_name": "hello",
        "username": "hello"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Для начала нужно узнать id бота:

```
print(bot.get_me())
```

> 'id': 123, 'is_bot': True, 'first_name': 'Bot', 'username': 'bot_bot',
> 'last_name': None, 'language_code': None, 'can_join_groups': True,
> 'can_read_all_group_messages': False, 'supports_inline_queries':
> False}

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['new_chat_members'])
def welcome_new_member(message):
    if message.json['new_chat_participant']['id'] == 123:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'всем чмоки в этом чатике')
```

таким образом, если бота добавят в группу, то он сразу же отправит указанное сообщение